# Does a Spring java gateway run on the browser, or does it run on a server as a separate application?

Tags: java, spring

I'm sure this is very obvious, but I'm new and just trying to wrap my head around this. And googling this question isn't helping, because I think the answer is just so obvious... but I'd really appreciate an answer.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, there are many modules Spring provides for a variety of applications. For applications like job scheduling, console applications, batch or stream processing, serverless applications, etc. you don't require any kind of server or browser.

But, when it comes to a web or enterprise application, you definitely need a web container. Spring comes with a built-in server of its own, i.e Tomcat (though there is also an option for Jetty and UnderTow, etc.). This is basically a container that handles the dynamic requests coming from the clients. But, you can have your own configuration by modifying the default one to meet your custom requirements. Like say, for example, Usually, it runs on port no.-8080 you can change it to say, 8081 by simply mentioning 'server.port=8081' in the application property of your application.

Now, coming back to your question any Spring/Spring Boot application runs on servers as a whole and sole application.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

So the tech stack is an angular webapp, that makes API requests that are channeled through a Java gateway. This java gateway uses the Spring framework.

So if I understand your answer correctly, you're saying that that java gateway is running as its own app, and is not running in the browser? 

So for instance.. when a user goes to our webpage, our server serves the webapp to the user... but the java gateway is not sent to the user? 

I'm a little confused because when you create a JAR file using maven, it bundles the java gateway and the webapp together.

Comment: I'm still confused about the gateway your talking about, like if you are refering to the gateway which holds the endpoint communication with other applications then I can say it's all bundled into a single application, as you mentioned, within the JAR. but my point is when you are considering the whole application in a bundle if it's web then definitely it requires a web container.

Comment: Yes it is the gateway with the end point communication

So you say it is bundled into a single app. But then when it all is running, it is separated into an angular app that is running in the browser and the java app that is running on a server in a web container?